# Android studio Create Button transparent round button

Tags: android-studio, android-layout, android-xml, android-button

I want to create button search and  like camera same  deaing facebook  button reals
In xml

Like this

[image]

Comment: use `Floating Action Button` to make this type of button

Answer (score 0):

set backgound of button as `android:background="#80000000"`